# Could not find Controller method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

in this my Form i have simple update form and i can fill input tags from Model. but after clicking on submit button to send input values i get this error :

```
Controller method not found.
```

my form:

```
{{Form::model( array('route'=>array('admin.profile.update',$profile->id), 'method'=>'post')) }}
```

my route:

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=> 'admin' ,'before'=>'auth'), function(){
    Route::controller('profile', 'profileController', array('getIndex'=>'profile.index', 'postUpdate'=>'profile.update'));
});
```

my controller:

```
class ProfileController extends \BaseController {

    protected $layout = 'layouts.admin.main';

    function __construct() {
        $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('except' => array('getIndex', 'postUpdate')));
        $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on' => 'post'));
    }    
    public function getIndex()
    {

    }

    public function postUpdate($id)
    {

    }
}
```

RESULT of html :

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://localhost/alachiq/admin/profile/index" method="POST"><input type="hidden" value="fDhe6m2qHh7NOERQaGvwDPJwCkbGTIRr56IBHseI" name="_token">
```

action of form is :

```
http://localhost/alachiq/admin/profile/index
```

that must be:

```
http://localhost/alachiq/admin/profile/update
```

artisan route:

```
GET admin/profile/index/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}   | profile.index  | profileController@getIndex 

GET admin/profile                                                |                | profileController@getIndex  

POST admin/profile/update/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?} | profile.update | profileController@postUpdate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your put a 'named route' here;

```
{{Form::model( array('route'=>array('admin.profile.update',$profile->id), 'method'=>'post')) }}
```

But your route name is "profile.update" (as shown in your artisan route list) - so change it to

```
{{Form::model( array('route'=>array('profile.update',$profile->id), 'method'=>'post')) }}
```

**Edit:** I see the problem now. You've done Form::model() instead of Form::open(), but you havent actually passed a model to the form. Either you need to pass in your model like this:

```
{{Form::model($model, array('route'=>array('profile.update',$profile->id), 'method'=>'post'))
```

or change your Form to open like this:

```
{{Form::open( array('route'=>array('profile.update',$profile->id), 'method'=>'post'))
```

There may or maybe still be an issue with the route name as well.

Comment: thats not correct and i get error after change to that